# Fastest way to delete all records from a WebSql/IndexedDb table using JayData

Tags: indexeddb, web-sql, jaydata

I have an application that could potentially hold 600k+ records in a single `WebSql` table.

I have searched and searched for a way in `JayData` to quickly delete all of the records from a table but the only option that I have found is to actually first retrieve the records, remove them from the set, and then call `saveChanges()` on the set.

As you can imagine, this is extremely slow (takes minutes). I find it hard to believe that there is no way to truncate a `WebSql` or `IndexedDb` table from `JayData`. Am I wrong about this or is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this requirement, the simple case is if you want to drop all the records from all tables and start with a clean database.

The constructor of the EntityContext accepts a `dbCreation` parameter:

```
var context = new Northwind({ name: 'webSql', databaseName: 'Northwind', dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropAllExistingTables });
```

The `DropAllExistingTables` creation type instructs JayData to delete not only all the records, but all the tables - and re-creates it during all context creation. This way you would loose your entire database while your application starts, so do not specify this dbCreation to your "main" context, but create a new one only if you need to clean the DB - and set the context instance reference to your main context.

```
var context = new Nortwind({name: 'webSql', databaseName: 'Northwind'});
//... your app logic ...
var cleanContext = new Nortwind({name: 'webSql', databaseName: 'Northwind', dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropAllExistingTables});
context = cleanContext;
// ...
```

In case you use IndexedDB, you should close the existing context before creating the cleanContext:

```
if (context.storageProvider.db) {
    context.storageProvider.db.close();
}
```

The tricky part comes if you want to keep some of your data, because in this case you need two schemas, two DBs, two contexts and clean only the one that contains the deletable records.

Comment: That is the tricky part.  I only need to clear a single table but want to retain the data in the other tables.  I was hoping that there would be a cleaner way :-/

Comment: There is no general way to support clearing a single table because of the possible relations.

Answer (score 0):

Their are two methods for that either you can use native javascript or jaydata
you need to **call the bellow function from any controller**

```
 DropTable("fav_master",fav_master);
```

you must write this function in controller only code of function is as bellow

**Method 1**

```
        function DropTable(TableName,TableObj){
        var db = window.openDatabase("ROW_DB", "", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name ='"+ TableName +"'");
            tx.executeSql("delete from '"+ TableName +"'");

            }); 
        }
       }
```

Here i am giving version of database blank because at the time of creation

**Method 2**

```
       function DropTable(TableName,TableObj){
        var db = window.openDatabase("ROW_DB", "", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name ='"+ TableName +"'");


            });

        var search;
        var promise =  TableObj.readAll();
        promise.then(function (dataset) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.DataSet = dataset;
                for (var x=0;x<$scope.DataSet.length;x++){
                    //console.log("Data"+$scope.DataSet[x].Id);
                    datarow=$scope.DataSet[x];
                    datarow.remove()
                    .then(function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                           var dataset = $scope.DataSet;
                           dataset.splice(dataset.indexOf(datarow), 1);
                        });
                    })
                   .fail(function(err) {
                       alert("Error deleting item");
                   });
                }
            });
        }); 
    }
```